# Add more links to the Dropdown Menu of meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

After a user logs in to a site using `meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` package, the dropdown created by `{{loginButtons}}` shows 2 buttons.

How can we add more buttons to the dropdown menu?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to customize the package. It should be inside your project's `packages/` directory. The file that controls this dropdown is [`login_buttons_dropdown.html`](https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/blob/master/login_buttons_dropdown.html).

Note that running `mrt update` might affect your changes to meteorite packages. You might want to rename the package folder to something like `accounts-ui-bootstrap-3-custom/`, do an `mrt remove accounts-ui-bootstrap-3`, and then `mrt add accounts-ui-bootstrap-3-custom`.

Comment: Is it possible to make the additions without editing the package files? Like injecting code at runtime.

Comment: Since it is all javascript, you can actually inject extra markup in there using jquery.

Comment: Yes, you can easily inject new HTML elements all you want. See my answer below. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to make additions without editing the package files, like injecting code at runtime. Assuming you use iron:router, you can inject HTML code in the client every time before a page renders:

```
var addExtraHTML = function() {
  var user = Meteor.user();
  //check if user is signed in and that desired HTML element does not already exists
  if (user && $('#idOfDesiredHTMLElement').length===0) {
    var newHTML = "<a href='#' class='btn btn-default btn-block' id='idOfDesiredHTMLElement'>Edit Account</a>";
    //Add desired HTML above the change password button
    $('#login-buttons-open-change-password').before(newHTML);
  }
  this.next();
};

Router.onBeforeAction(addExtraHTML); //Injects HTML every time before the page loads
```

Make sure to give the things you add an id, so that you can keep track of what is already there!

Answer (score 0):

Meteor has changed since the last answer was valid.

The way I got it to work was by attaching to the onRender event of the dropdown template from the accounts-ui package.

Tested on:
**METEOR@1.1.0.3 - accounts-ui-unstyled@1.1.7**

```
Template._loginButtonsLoggedInDropdownActions.onRendered(function() {

  // Validate user exists and YOUR ELEMENT is not already in place
  if (Meteor.user() && $('#YOUR_ELEMENT').length === 0) {

    // Inject YOUR ELEMENT before the 'Change password' button
    $('#login-buttons-open-change-password').before('<div class="login-button" id="YOUR_ELEMENT">YOUR_ELEMENT</div>');

    // EXTRA: Attach an event to YOUR ELEMENT
    $('#login-buttons-open-account-page').on('click', function() {
      // Event Action...
    });
  }
});
```